# Output values into a list

Tags: python, list, output

I am using a kinect to get position data, using the module pykinect.
The problem is that it returns me position data for each gap of time, so the output looks like this:

```
output x_data:
...
(0.04)
(0.06)
(0.069)
(0.072)
(0.08)
(0.074)
(0.071)
```

So when I call `x_data`, it only returns the last value (in this case `0.071`), so `x_data` is not a list or a tuple.
I need the position values as a list, so I can use them later.

Does anyone know how to take all the values of the output and save them into a single list? Because the value of `x_data` is changing due to time passing, the question is how can I save the values of the output in a list.

Comment: what have you tried? can you not just use `list.append` on what you are outputting as you go along?

Comment: are you getting the information in real-time, basically as it comes do you get it

Comment: Is `x_data` a function or a variable? You wrote first __call__ and later "Because the value of x_data is changing due to time passing".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when you (can) call/read `x_data`, but if it is a loop or after a time interval you can use the following code:

```
data_x = []  # create empty list data_x (not to confuse with x_data)

# some other code

# run repeatedly:
data_x.append(x_data())  # I don't know if x_data is a function or a variable
                         # if it's a variable remove the inner parenthesis
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing real-time position data, you will probably have loads of values -- using a list for doing anything with this will be incredibly slow. You should consider using a pre-allocated numpy array instead. It's hard to know without more details what is the best option for your application, however.